# NullPointerException from build toolchain

Tags: android

My computer suddenly shut down while executing android studio due power failure.
after restarting, when i run my app it show error below.

```
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
Error:java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

and i reinstalled sdk and android studio. but same error is showing.
please any one help for this issue...

Comment: My guess is something in the toolchain got corrupted (maybe gradle since the sdk and android studio got re-installed?). you might also need to ```clean``` your project if something in your project got screwed up (note i said project, as in your code not sdk/android studio.)

Comment: thank you Neil Locketz.
i clean an rerun it.
its working fine.

Comment: Just curious, let me know if you got it working/how. Thanks ^_^

Answer (score -1):

Clean your project and rebuild. This problem is due to build files getting corrupted.

If problem not solved then goto file amd choose invalidate cache and restart in Android Studio menu.